# Deep clone child class

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class `Player`, which plays several games of Roulette (samples). For each game, the desired player is cloned into a session method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
{
    IList<int> sessionStakes = this.Session(player.DeepClone() as Player);
    this.maxima.Add(sessionStakes.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Last());
    this.durations.Add(sessionStakes.Count);
}
```

This clone method is used in `Player` like so:

```
public virtual Player DeepClone()
{
    return this.MemberwiseClone() as Player;
}
```

And for specific implementations of `Player`, I have additional information such as a list of bet values:

```
public IList<int> betValues;
public CancellationPlayer(int startingMoney, Table table, int numberOfRounds) : base(startingMoney, table, numberOfRounds)
{          
    betValues = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    bet = new Bet(this, betValues.First() + betValues.Last(), table.GetOutcome("Black"));
}
```

I need to override the `DeepClone()` method to reset this value as values are added and removed during play - I need a fresh `Player` for each "Session".

```
public override Player DeepClone()
{
    this.betValues = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    return base.DeepClone();
}
```

I'm just wondering if there are any comments on the best way of handling cloning. I've never really come across cloning before and something about this seems really off, especially when child classes aren't forced to implement `DeepClone()` it may seem like it's doing something it's not.

EDIT: Here is a link to the full project https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz-njBI20A1tSXc5anVVbXVoSTQ.

The reason I'm cloning is because `Simulator` takes a player and then need to create a new player for each session but I'm not sure how to do that without putting the Gather() logic in the main `Program` below.

```
Random random = new Random();
Wheel wheel = new Wheel(random);
Table table = new Table(wheel, 1, 50000);
RouletteGame rg = new RouletteGame(wheel, table);
Player player = new CancellationPlayer(100, table, 250);
Simulator simulator = new Simulator(rg, player, 50);

var lists = simulator.Gather();
foreach (var session in lists.First().Zip(lists.ElementAt(1), (first, second) => string.Format("Ending Value: {0}, Duration: {1}", first, second)))
    Console.WriteLine(session.ToString());

Console.Read();
```

Comment: Cloning a `Player` like that feels like a very weird thing to do. Why don't you post all of your program for review instead of asking this question with decontextualized excerpts, so that we can advise you properly?

Comment: I agree with @200_success - very strange implementation. Also, [`Object.MemberwiseClone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx) performs a *shallow* copy - so method name `DeepClone()` is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the main post with the project and reasons I was thinking at the time.

Comment: Please [follow the tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Including a link to your project on Google Drive isn't according to our rules.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I can't see any documentation on not including Google Drive can you be more specific or suggest an alternative?

Comment: @NickSpicer It's fine to link to an external resource but your question must stand on its own. In this case... it does, but barely. Voted to leave open.

Comment: From "How do I ask...": "Be sure to embed the code you want reviewed in the question itself; you can leave supporting, but non-essential, code in links to other sites. Strip out sensitive information such as passwords, but do not alter the code so much that it no longer resembles your original work."

Comment: That said, this is a bad question (I downvoted) and should be edited. It is answerable but reads poorly and would do better if it was presented as a few class files with methods stripped out for brevity, rather than these short snippets.

Comment: @Pimgd Thanks for the insight, I'll post a better phrased question next time but wanted to avoid being too verbose. I do believe additional code would not help convey the message but it does look unstructured with the edit.

Comment: @NickSpicer my suggestion would be - post a class, then cut out all the methods and instance variables you think are not relevant, replacing them with a comment. The result is easier to understand. And if someone says "I don't get it, I'm lacking context" you add some of those methods back, because they're interested in helping you and if you help people help you you are basically helping yourself (which is what you want, to be helped, right?). Anyway, that's what to do the next time. And 250 line classes are perfectly fine for a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ought to do is make a copy constructor, then have the "clone" method return a `new Player` or `new CancellationPlayer`. That way both internal state is preserved, but simulations are possible.